# Response variable in randomForest

Tags: r, random-forest

My question is - how to parametrise RandomForest. Let me give working code.

Following works properly

```
library(randomForest) # load the package
data(iris) # load data
fit <- randomForest(Species~., data=iris) # fit model
predictions <- predict(fit, iris[,1:4]) # make predictions
```

when line3 is replaced with

```
fit <- randomForest(iris[,5]~., data=iris) # fit model
```

then line4 (predictions ) gives error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Species' not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the default S3 method of the `randomForest` function to do this:

Instead of:

```
fit <- randomForest(iris[,5]~., data=iris) # fit model
```

Just use:

```
fit2 <- randomForest(iris[-5], iris$Species , data=iris) # fit model
#or
fit2 <- randomForest(iris[-5], iris[,5] , data=iris) # fit model
```

And this way you can parameterise it. First argument is the data.frame without the Species column (i.e. the data.frame without the response data) and second argument is the response vector i.e. Species.

```
> fit

Call:
 randomForest(formula = Species ~ ., data = iris) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 4%
Confusion matrix:
           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
setosa         50          0         0        0.00
versicolor      0         47         3        0.06
virginica       0          3        47        0.06
```

And

```
> fit2

Call:
 randomForest(x = iris[-5], y = iris$Species, data = iris) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 4%
Confusion matrix:
           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
setosa         50          0         0        0.00
versicolor      0         47         3        0.06
virginica       0          3        47        0.06
```

Comment: @Shiv You are very welcome ! I am glad it helps :). I would also advice you to have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) about how to accept an answer that has worked for you (by clicking the tick icon next to an answer) . Accepting an answer is not compulsory but is encouraged when it has helped you since many more people having the same issue can benefit from seeing it. It also gives you and the person who answered reputation points that allow you to use more features (privileges) on stackoverflow.